# Why is my display template not applying classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have DisplayTemplates for `String` and `DateTime?`, like these:

```
@model String
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model, new { @class="read-only"})

@model DateTime?
@{
    String modelValue = "";
    if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            modelValue = Model.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", modelValue, new { @class = "date-picker date-text read-only", @readonly="readonly" })
```

I do this because when I use the helper `DisplayFor` I prefer a textbox with a darker background, and I like to tag on the `date-picker` class to later transform these fields to proper date pickers.

The class `read-only` just defines the background colour. In this excerpt from the model,

```
[Editable(false)]
[Display(Name = "File Name")]
public string FileName { get; set; }

[Editable(false)]
[Display(Name = "File Report Date")]
public DateTime? FileReportDate { get; set; }
```

two properties are nearly identical, yet the display template for `String` refuses to add the `read-only` class, where the template for `DateTime` does it just right.

Why is there such a difference, and why won't my display template add a class to its inner `input` element?

**ADDED:** It seems the template for String is not being used at all. Why would this be?

Comment: Does the addition @readonly="readonly" help? Just like you added for the date-picker?

Comment: Are you sure your display template its being called? If you add something else to the template like a dummy text, does it appears next to the textbox? I just placed you template code in a file /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/String.cshtml and doing `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)` in the login form of a new MVC internet application shows a textbox with the read-only class

Comment: @DanielJ.G. It looks like your are correct and the template isn't even being called. Now I'm puzzled and relieved at the same time.

Comment: How is the view calling the template, `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FieldName)? If you set breakpoint in the view just when calling the template for that property, and use step into, does it picks another template? I would also check what happens adding the attribute `[UIHint("String")]` to your property... I guess both templates are located in the same place?

Comment: Where are these templates located? By default, it should be in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml Also, check the casing, it's possible that you need to use `string` instead of `String`